# Implementing service-oriented architecture using REST architecture

Tags: rest, web-services, service, soa

I have the following questions:

Which steps should my work consist of when implementing SOA using REST architecture (RESTful webservices)?
Is there a step called "Registering services" when dealing with REST?

I am looking forward to your answers)

Answer (score 0):

Service orientation is an architecture style where you decide you system into autonomous components. REST (originally) is another architecture style they share some common traits and you can build a RESTful SOA.

[image]

I am guessing though, that by REST you mean communication by web calls on top of HTTP and in that case it is just an implementation detail on how the services talk to each other